# Expectation of the sum of the last decreasing sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, expected-value

Given $n$ cards, labelled $1$ to $n$, what is the expectation of the sum of the last decreasing sequence?

e.g. 
$n=4$
Then {$1,2,3,4$} gives $0$,
whilst {$2,1,3,4$} gives $2+1=3$
and {$3,4,1,2$} gives $4+1=5$
I tried using recursion and inserting the new $(n+1)^{th}$ card at different points of old sequences, but it didn't work.

Comment: What approach will be used to solve such a problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is one of those classic problems (or their variations) that are long solved. A quick and dirty program enumerating all the permutations yields for $n = 1$ to $10$ the expectations of $\left\{1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{11}{3},\frac{137}{24},\frac{89}{12},\frac{1279}{144},\frac{5155}{504},\frac{154951}{13440},\frac{2325293}{181440},\frac{51161063}{3628800}\right\}$, which looks quite linear when plotted (ten points is far from suggestive for asymptotic trend).

Comment: I got zero hit in [OEIS](https://oeis.org) for the numerators (when the denominators are forced back to the factorials) $\{1, 3, 22, 137, 890, 6395, 51550, 464853, 4650586, 51161063\}$. Not even many relevant Google hits for the partial sequence $\{22, 137, 890, 6395\}$

Comment: Thank you very much. I verified your answers by hand for n = 1,2,3,4. Given that the answers computed are not 'nice' numbers I do not think there is a good recursion, nor is there a closed form for this problem!

Comment: It's really hard to say at this point. A tiny change in the definition might give some numbers that are more recognizable (or in some database). For example, a closely related (but NOT equivalent) problem is to find the expectation of sum of the first-increasing-sequence. Hopefully some users who are more familiar with the relevant combinatorial analysis can notice this post and chime in.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationRun.html See if anything useful can be started with this Permutation Run.